# Unique Particle Attribution Exception when i use <xsd:any> within <xsd:choice>

Tags: xml, validation

I need either `apps` element or other element defined in some other xsd (which I am importing through `<xsd:any>` ) or both. I have used `choice` but it is throwing Unique Particle Attribution Exception.

```
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element name="apps" />
        <xsd:any minOccurs="0" namespace="##local" />
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:sequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because the XML processor does not know where your apps alement belongs to. xsd:element or xsd:any. It cannot do a look-ahead. Choose another namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Unique Particle Attribution helps prevent ambiguity - where you have the apps element defined alongside the xsd:any, it is ambiguous whether the apps element is associated with the specific element declaration (**xsd:element name="apps"**) or with the wildcard (**xsd:any**).

Your question doesn't give enough detail for a full answer - are the other non "apps" elements completely unspecified? E.g. is it literally any element, or is it "apps" and other well defined choices? If you have can defined the other elements then add those as specified choices, otherwise you may as well use **xsd:any** without the need to define the "apps" element.

Comment: other elements are non "apps".

Comment: If the other elements are completely ambiguous, there's not much point in using 'xsd:choice' - it's there to provide a specific set of elements allowed in that position.

Comment: Is the 'apps' element mandatory? If so, add minOccurs="1" to its definition - that way, it should be able to be matched to its declaration (afaik).

Comment: apps is not mandatory. It may come or may not come. If it was mandatory, then no need of using choice

Comment: In which case, I can't really see the point in having "apps" declared if you're also going to use "xsd:any". If you don't have a defined set of choices, there's no point in using "xsd:choice" imho.

Answer (score 0):

Your schema is legal in XSD 1.1, which resolves the ambiguity by saying that a match against an explicit element declaration wins over a match against a wildcard. In XSD 1.0, however, you can't have a choice between a specific element and a wildcard if the namespaces allowed by the wildcard include the namespace of the specific element.

Comment: If i use 1.1 version it throws NullPointerExcepton

Comment: Really, Abhishek, while Java has ample libraries to work with XSD and XML, you should really consider getting yourself a program like Altova or Oxygen (or ..) for designing xsd.

Comment: What do you mean "it" throws NullPointerException. Presumably by "it" you mean your XSD processor - but you haven't told us which XSD processor you are using! (The ones that support XSD 1.1 are the latest releases of Saxon and Xerces).